# Unble to instntiate service firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:Didnt find class .MyFirebaseInstanceIdService

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When the first application is run, the error will come out. but if it has been opened for the second time, there is no error, and all functions in the application run normally.

I did not understand what happened, I checked again, but did not find a solution.

Here Is **AndroidManifiest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.myapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_kotak"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".controller.AppController"
    >
    <activity android:name=".Login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBejiBSsPwRJgso9ARbKCRhoJ8eowoqKWP"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <service android:name="firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:enabled="false" android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/mulaibelajar" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

And here **MyFirebaseInstanceIdService**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService{

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIdService";
    private static final String TOPIC_GLOBAL = "global";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(TOPIC_GLOBAL);

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Add Dot(.) in service Tag of the Manifest file.

Existing code

```
<service android:name="firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
```

You need to add dot here

```
 <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
```

I will explain that dot logic in detail

Omitting the dot and not fully qualifying the package/class name will work if and only if the specified class is not part of a subpackage within your application.

If your application package name is com.example.myapp, and you have an activity class `com.example.myapp.MyActivity`:

`android:name="MyActivity"` will work.
`android:name=".MyActivity"` will work.
`android:name="com.example.myapp.MyActivity"`will work.
But if you have the same application package and an activity class in a subpackage within your source tree such as `com.example.myapp.myactivities.MyActivity` things change.

`android:name=".myactivities.MyActivity"`will work
`android:name="com.example.myapp.myactivities.MyActivity"` will work
`android:name="MyActivity"` will not work
`android:name="myactivities.MyActivity"` will not work
3 doesn't work because that will infer that the class name you mean is actually `com.example.myapp.MyActivity` like in the first example above. A class with this name won't be found and you'll get an error.

4 doesn't work because it looks like a fully qualified class name, that is the system will interpret it to mean that myactivities.MyActivity is the fully qualified name itself, not the real name of `com.example.myapp.myactivities.MyActivity`.

You need the leading dot here to clarify that you're using a relative path, not an absolute path. If you specify just a class name with no package `info` at all, the system infers that the class is at the root of your application package hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but i am a xamarin.android developer and get same error yesterday while configuring firebase for push notification 
The problem is they change the api or class name(Something like that)
just uses All letest API and initialize your Firebase instance as described in official documentation (Don't go for old firebase tutorials)
Hope this will help you
Thanks

Comment: thanks for answer, im using firebase-messaging:17.1.0 and firebase-core:16.0.1.